# jruby rails 3 and warbler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jruby, warbler

I am trying to make a deployment war. I have the jdbc-mysql, activerecord-jdbcmysql-adapter and warbler gems installed.  I have edited config/database.yml and changed the adapter to jdbcmysql... but I can not even run warble config without getting this error message:

```
Could not find gem 'mysql2 (>= 0, runtime)' in any of the gem sources.
```

Any warble command I try I get this...  Anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.  There is a new file in Rails 3 called Gemfile.  I had to comment out the line that said "gem mysql2".